# Get instances of generic class for specific type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have generic class `Module` with `EntityBase` template parameter.

```
public class Module<TEntity> : where TEntity : EntityBase 
{
}

public class City : EntityBase {}
public class Country : EntityBase {}
...
```

Can I use autofac to get instances of Module class with specific class as template param?

E.g. `Module<City>`, `Module<Country>`. I don't want to inherit `Module<T>` for every class in my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register the module with your container like so:

```
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Module<>>)
    .AsSelf();
```

And then you can inject them into your service's constructor:

```
public SomeService(Module<City> cityModule, Module<Country> countryModule)
```

You can see more examples in the documentation [here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components).